# How to clean up my find or create code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code to find the row in database or else create a new row. Is working but it look very ugly and hard to maintain.

```
return_policy_id= MyEbayReturnPolicy.find_or_create_by_active_and_name_and_ebay_marketplace_id_and_returns_within_and_returns_accepted_and_warranty_offered_and_warranty_duration_and_warranty_type_and_shipping_costs_paid_by_and_refunds(active,name,ebay_marketplace_id,returns_within,returns_accepted,warrenty_offered,warranty_duration,warranty_type,shipping_costs_paid_by,refunds)
```

Here is the find_or_create code

```
 def self.find_or_create(search, *args, &block)
    parameters = search.split("_and_")
    params = Hash[ parameters.zip(args) ]
    obj = where(params).first 
    if(obj.nil?)
       obj = self.new(params);
       obj.save
    end
    return obj;
  end
```

As you can see is extremely long line of code.

I wanted to know if there's a better approach to make this code look nice and clean so easy for maintain.

Thanks!

Comment: use scopes + where clauses. I confirm it's unreadable

Comment: Can't you just use scopes and/or simple conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3.2 introduced [first_or_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create) (among other similar methods). You can take advantage of it:

```
MyEbayReturnPolicy.where(
    active:                 active,
    name:                   name,
    ebay_marketplace_id:    ebay_marketplace_id,
    returns_within:         returns_within,
    returns_accepted:       returns_accepted,
    warranty_offered:       warranty_offered,
    warranty_duration:      warranty_duration,
    warranty_type:          warranty_type,
    shipping_costs_paid_by: shipping_costs_paid_by,
    refunds:                refunds
).first_or_create
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my suggestion
It's too many conditions,create `scope` for above attributes you can do this via some sort of meta programming way also to reduce code,
first find out by chaining scope if it's found then return or create record